# How to install jwdp dependencies while using Jlink

Tags: java, docker, debugging, jlink, jdwp

I am creating a container with a spring boot application. Java and required modules are installed using `jlink`. It looks like this:

```
RUN jlink --compress=2 --no-header-files --no-man-pages \
     --add-modules java.base,java.desktop,java.instrument,java.logging,java.sql,java.xml \
     --output /opt/jre
```

and the entry point looks like:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -jar /app.jar"]
```

The container start up fails as the JVM can not find native library for `jdwp`. There is no documentation for `jlink` to include `jdwp` binaries. May be it is by design that a minimal run-time need not support debugging.

So I attempted to put the required library manually into `/opt/jre/lib` of the container. I copied `libjdwp.so` from a linux vm running OpenJDK 11 and placed that in to my container using:

```
ADD libjdwp.so /opt/jre/lib/
```

This caused a crash at start up:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000001e66, pid=1, tid=6
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu11.33+15-CA) (11.0.4+11) (build 11.0.4+11-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.4+11-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000001e66
```

Has anyone figured a consistent way to provide jdwp to java VM started with `jlink` ?

Comment: You probably need to copy `libdt_socket.so` as well.

Comment: Thanks but adding `libdt_socket.so` has not helped @b0gusb

Answer (score 5):

You will need to add the jdwp openjdk [module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk.jdwp.agent-summary.html)

```
RUN jlink --compress=2 --no-header-files --no-man-pages \
 --add-modules java.base,java.desktop,java.instrument,java.logging,java.sql,java.xml,jdk.jdwp.agent \
 --output /opt/jre
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me today.